# Mysql Error - 1251 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I know that this question was already answered in SO, but the suggested fixxes dont work for me!

Error:

```
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Programmierung\FitnessAppExpo\server\server.js:29:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)    
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true
}
```

I have a Xampp Server running with myphpadmin on localhost. I tried to insert this code in myphpadmin:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
```

But if I try to use this it gives me an error inside phpmyadmin:

> Missing ',' before start of a new ALTER operation!

and a second one stating:

> Unknown ALTER operation (near by)

Is there something special I need to do when I want to use or execute this command inside phpmyadmin? Because the way that the ALTER Query is written doesnt let me execute it..

Node (Express) Code:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var app = express();
var cors = require("cors");

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "ssshhhhh",
    saveUninitialized: true, // (default: true)
    resave: true
  })
);

app.use(cors({ origin: ["http://localhost:4200"], credentials: true }));

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  // host: "127.0.0.1:3307",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "fitness_app"
});

con.connect(err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database connected -> ");
});

var server = app.listen(8090, () => {
  var host = "localhost";
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

~Faded

Comment: node-mysql version? MySQL server version? `SHOW CREATE USER root@localhost`?

Comment: mysql version is 2.18.1 express version: 4.17.1 // localhost users I dont create them but they exist in the db there are 3 root users

Comment: `SELECT VERSION()` to show the server version. `SHOW CREATE USER` to show the plugin defined by the user. Do [any of these issues](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE) look familiar?

Comment: This is my log after select version: 10.4.11-MariaDB
 and this is the create user: CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: If the full info was included it would probably show an auth_socket plugin. This seems to one of the existing nodejs bugs. Recommend creating a new user for application use. Package updates depend on the root user so best leave it along. MariaDB and mysql support effectively an unlimited number of database users.

Comment: I created a new user and changed my code in nodejs to this user now i am getting this error: code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045, - trying to fixx this now.

Comment: Okay so I fixxed my Issue for now.. My problem was that I had to change the port to 3307 and I did not change this in my NodeJS Server file. @danblack thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following query in MYSQL Workbench

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Where root as your user localhost as your URL and password as your password

Then run this query to refresh privileges:

```
flush privileges;
```

Try connecting using node after you do so.

If that doesn't work, try it without @'localhost' part.